# Почему нет доступа к методу wall.post?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

У меня есть один плагин, который отправляет некоторую информацию на стену группы вконтакте. Плагин работает на javascript и постит все как надо без проблем, но выскакивает всплывающее окно каждый раз.
Решил переделать его под php, чтобы скрипт работал менее напряжно для пользователя.

В scope пишу "photos,wall,groups,offline,nohttps", в итоге получаю:

[image: Окно подтверждения ВК]

Ничего о постинге на стену нет.

Ну и, как результат:

```
{"error":"wall.post. 15","error_description":"Access denied: no access to call this method"}
```

Хотя перед этим авторизация прошла успешно и картинки загрузились в фотоальбом группы.

Приложение standalone, должно все работать. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я бы начал с поддержки контакта, но на всякий случай убедитесь, что приложение действительно standalone и использует соответствующий oauth flow (насколько понимаю, окно выше соответствует общению с вебсайтом, а standalone шлет логин-пароль): ***Note that this access permission is unavailable for sites (it is ignored at attempt of authorization)***

Comment: На всякий случай пересоздал приложение. Но результат тот же. Меня тоже смущает фраза: Note that this access permission is unavailable for sites (it is ignored at attempt of authorization). Но ведь через яваскрипт работает с того же сайта и с теми же данными. Не пойму в чем разница?..

Comment: Там три flow для трех типов клиентов. Вы, очевидно, используете то, что называется server flow, поэтому вк игнорирует реальный тип приложения и воспринимает его как сайт. Либо там действительно внутри ошибка, и тогда вам точно в техподдержку.

Comment: А как можно задать тот тип flow, который позволит публиковать на стену?

Comment: Если я задаю $callback_url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html'; то я получаю нужные права, но улетаю на чужой сайт. Как получить code на своем сайте например во всплывающем окне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации ясно написано (http://vk.com/dev/permissions):

> Доступ к обычным и расширенным методам работы со стеной. 
>   Внимание, данное право доступа недоступно для сайтов (игнорируется при попытке авторизации).

а в описании к `wall.post` (http://vk.com/dev/wall.post) написано следующее:

> Данный метод доступен только Standalone-приложениям и web-приложениям, использующим окно подтверждения.

Comment: Сцуки вк ........

Answer (score 1):

Создаем ссылку на страницу запроса code. Обратите внимание, что в строках есть переменные: `$appID` - ID приложения, `$appKey` -секретный ключ приложения, `$code` - временный код полученный на первом шаге.

```
   $authLink = <<<TEXT
        <a target="_blank"
            class="adm-btn js-code-get"                
            href="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=$appID&v=5.103&display=popup&scope=photos,friends,notify,groups,offline,wall,market&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html">
            $codeLinkCaption
        </a>
TEXT
```

Далее просим пользователя скопировать код из строки адреса.

Затем:

```
    $urlToken = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=$appID&client_secret=$appKey&code=$code&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html";
    $result = HttpHelper::curlGetJsonToArray($urlToken);
    $token = $result['access_token'];
```

Сохраняем токен и пользуемся.