# Постинг на стену группы VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Прошу помощи! Не получается сделать постинг на стену в ВК.
Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно!? Спасибо!

---

Делаю следующим образом:

**1. Авторизация пользователя через oauth**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
$auth_get_code = array(
            'v'             => $version,
            'client_id'     => $client_id,
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
            'response_type' => 'code',      //тип данных для получения
            'scope'         => 'email,'     //дополнительно запрашиваем email пользователя
                            //. 'offline,'     //срок жизни ключа - без срока годности
                            . 'wall,'       //доступ к публикации на стене  
                            . 'friends,'
                            . 'groups,'
                            . 'photos,'
                            . 'notify',    
        );
        print '<p><a href="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($auth_get_code)) . '">Аутентификация через ВКонтакте</a></p>';
```

---

**2. Получение токена**

```html
$params = array(
            'v'             => $version,
            'client_id'     => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'code'          => $get_code,
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
        );
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
```

---

**3. Попытка постинга на стену группы**

```html
$wallpost_params = array(
            'v'             => $version,
            'access_token'  => $sitesess['access_token'],
            'owner_id'      => '-' . $wall_id,
            'message'       => '123',
        );
        $wallpost = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($wallpost_params))), true);
```

---

в результате получаю ответ с ошибкой 15

> Access denied: no access to call this method

```html
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"},{"key":"v","value":"5.87"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"-ХХХХХХХ"},{"key":"message","value":"123"}]}}
```

Comment: Вы не получите доступ к стене с токеном, чем свое приложение-standalone, насколько я помню ВК сделал так для защиты от спама. Подробнее читаем [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/permissions), и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455706/285292)

Comment: я использую Standalone приложение, права указаны....

Comment: читаем внимательно, свои сайты с авторизацией с токеном не будут вам доступ давать к стене и ещё некоторым методам.

Comment: а как же тогда работают сайты подобные smmbox com